# Microsoft bot framework review process

Tags: botframework, microsoft-skype-bot

I have been trying to publish my Skype bot to Microsoft Bot Directory, it has been almost two weeks and it is still in review.

My questions are:

1. Do they have a list of must haves for the bot so that they can only accept it if it fulfills these requirements? They didn't reject mine either but I will be prepared in advance in case they do.
2. If yes where can I find this info?
3. Has anyone here submitted their bot and how long did it take for them to be published?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a few months ago and it is still not approved.

The bot directory is very selective and they won't approve you unless it's a full fledged mature application.

Plus, they also claim that their reviewing resources are very limited.

I'd say don't expect to get approved.

And no, they don't have any kind of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few items that might help with guidance:

- [MICROSOFT BOT FRAMEWORK– PREVIEW ONLINE SERVICES AGREEMENT](https://www.botframework.com/Content/Microsoft-Bot-Framework-Preview-Online-Services-Agreement.htm)
- [Bot review guidelines](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/directory/review-guidelines/)
- [Developer Code of Conduct for the Microsoft Bot Framework](https://www.botframework.com/Content/Developer-Code-of-Conduct-for-Microsoft-Bot-Framework.htm)

It takes a few days (maybe a little longer) to get a response from a review. A couple items that caught me off guard were their logo requirements, which are very precise, and the welcome/help message needs to be complete. You also need to specify your Terms of Use and Privacy Policy well. Looking at these documents, there are probably several more items that are likely to trip-up submission.

Comment: Me too, one month and still in review!